# How to create a library out of tensorflow lite for microcontrollers?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite

After successfully trying out the examples for microcontrollers in the tensorflow lite repository, I would now like to be able to use this in my existing application. I figured that the right way to do this, is to create a library from these examples where I can call a function with input data, which will then return the output data. I was essentially wondering two things:

- Is this the right way to go about it? Or would it perhaps be better to not create a library, but generate source code that I then compile in my own toolchain?
- If it is the right way, how do I do it?

I did find a library with all functions(I think) called `libtensorflow-microlite.a`, but this is more than 10 MB, which I think is much too big.

Comment: If it's too big you'll need to explain your resource constraints.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the linker just link in the exact functions used, so even if a .a binary file is 10 MB, it's possible including it and using portions of it would produce a project file for you that's much less--perhaps 1 MB, no? In other words, just because you include a 10MB .a file it does NOT mean it will all go into your project to produce an output that is increased by 10MB in size.

Comment: You might want to check out frugally-deep as a lightweight-alternative for running (but not training) a neural network:  https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep

Comment: @GabrielStaples, the examples are compiled down to ~20KB in size, which includes the parameters and the like. I would agree that compiling that 10MB library might result in only 1MB end result, but I need it to be only a few KB.

Comment: A few KB? That's impossible. A single pseudo random number generator could be a few KB, let alone an entire tensor flow usage. I think you need to get a large 32 bit microcontroller with 2MB flash memory or so for this task. Ex: STM32F7 or STM32H7.

Comment: @GabrielStaples see this example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/examples/magic_wand
It's a 20 kilobyte neural network

Comment: *It's a 20 kilobyte neural network* - Can you use it? If not why?